# Group by in webpart page with URL filter webpart

Tags: 2013, list-view, grouping

I think this might be a bug. But wanting to check if it is me doing something wrong or if it is genuinely a bug...

I have a sharepoint webpart page. It includes a list view webpart, as well as a URL query string webpart. In its default list view state, the page worked fine. The URL query string webpart correctly filtered the list, and it only showed the correct entries.

First problem:
The page refreshes in something like a minute, after which the filter is now deactivated. The URL still shows the correct URL filter. The little filter icon on the column still showed up correctly. When clicked on the filtered column, it correctly identifies the item it should filter for. However, the display of the items is messed up - the entire list showed up. I have determined this to be due to the asynchronous update of the list webpart. Is there a way to keep both?

Second problem:
Due to some text being too long, I was trying to use group by as a way to break the items down by description and people can get more info by clicking on them individually. This however, did not work as intended. While the items did showed as grouped by (in the first minute before the first problem hits), it does not render appropriately when the group is expanded. The title line identified correctly that the grouped by items only have (1) entry under them. But the expanded portion showed the entire filtered list. I cannot seem to determine what setting might have caused this. Any suggestions? (There are no folders within this list, or any goofy stuff like different content types and etc. This is just a plain old list).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some additional testing, it is determined that the second problem is also attributed to the enabling of asynchronous update of the list webpart. At this time, I do not see a published solution regarding this issue though it probably is not that critical.